# How can we delete existing role in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, roles

Is there a way to delete existing role in kubernetes? 
I have made a mistake while creating roles for the users and now I want to update or delete the role. Please let me know a way

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Delete a Role:

`kubectl delete role NAME_OF_ROLE -n NAMESPACE`

Delete RoleBinding:

`kubectl delete rolebinding NAME_OF_ROLEBINDING -n NAMESPACE`

Update Role:

`kubectl apply -f NEW_YAML_FILE_FOR_ROLE`

Update RoleBInding:

`kubectl apply -f NEW_YAML_FILE_FOR_ROLEBINDING`

Answer (score 3):

```
kubectl get clusterroles
kubectl get clusterrolebindings
find your role name and then delete
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding name
kubectl delete clusterrole name
```

courtesy : https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/discussion/858217/lab-10-1-how-to-delete-a-clusterrole-and-a-clusterrolebinding